# Download clipped Sentinel1-GRD data using bounding box or an AOI

Tags: clip, image, download, sentinel-1

I am using this code to download Sentinel-1 data. I am able to download a whole tile. I want to crop a specfic area and download that region using my AOI.

This is my code of Jupyter notebook-

```
pip install asf_search
conda install -c conda-forge asf_search
import asf_search as asf
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import box
from datetime import date 
### 1. Read Shapefile using Geopandas
gdf = gpd.read_file(path_to_shapefile)
### 2. Extract the Bounding Box Coordinates
bounds = gdf.total_bounds
### 3. Create GeoDataFrame of the Bounding Box 
gdf_bounds = gpd.GeoSeries([box(*bounds)])
### 4. Get WKT Coordinates
wkt_aoi = gdf_bounds.to_wkt().values.tolist()[0]
results = asf.search(
platform= asf.PLATFORM.SENTINEL1A,
processingLevel=[asf.PRODUCT_TYPE.SLC],
start = date(2017, 1, 1),
end = date(2017, 12, 31),
intersectsWith = wkt_aoi
)
print(f'Total Images Found: {len(results)}')
### Save Metadata to a Dictionary
metadata = results.geojson()
session = asf.ASFSession().auth_with_creds(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
results.download(
     path = path_to_download_directory,
     session = session, 
     processes = 2 
  )
```

Comment: I think you have to download the entire image and then subset to your AOI